# Запрос SQL на сортировку по времени авторизации

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, mysql

Всем привет. Просьба помочь, никак не соображу как подойти к задачке.

Есть табличка `users`, в ней есть два столбика:

- `last_login` время последней авторизации `activated_users`
- активировал ли пользователь аккаунт или нет: активирован = 1, не
  активирован = 0.

Как составить запрос чтобы выстроило активированных пользователей по дате авторизации, от ближайшей до самой давней.

Благодарю.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE activated_users = 1 ORDER BY last_login DESC` не?

Comment: высшая математика, не иначе.

Comment: Все приходит с опытом, благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев данный [Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  users
WHERE
  activated_users = 1
ORDER BY
  last_login DESC
```